# Is overbuffered done on 10th byte past alocated space?

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

I am reading [The Shellcoder's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047008023X), and having trouble with an exercise. I am trying to `jump` to an address after I exceed the buffer space. After 36 bytes I write a 4 byte payload with an address that overwrites the `ret` instruction so that address will be popped and moved to `eip`. At which point, I output the input twice (the second time is for the `jump` back to my payload).

The book lists the following C example:

```
void return_input(void){
    char ar[30];
    scanf(" %s", ar);
    printf("%s\n",ar);
}

int main (void) {

    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have a buffer that is 30 bytes in length.

A dump of the `main` function in assembly gives the following:

```
    0x0804919b <+0>:    push   %ebp
    0x0804919c <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x0804919e <+3>:    and    $0xfffffff8,%esp
    0x080491a1 <+6>:    call   0x8049172 <return_input> // here I want to jump
    0x080491a6 <+11>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x080491ab <+16>:   leave  
    0x080491ac <+17>:   ret
```

And the `return_input` function:

```
    0x08049172 <+0>:    push   %ebp
    0x08049173 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x08049175 <+3>:    sub    $0x20,%esp
    0x08049178 <+6>:    lea    -0x1e(%ebp),%eax
    0x0804917b <+9>:    push   %eax
    0x0804917c <+10>:   push   $0x804a008
    0x08049181 <+15>:   call   0x8049050 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
    0x08049186 <+20>:   add    $0x8,%esp
    0x08049189 <+23>:   sub    $0x4,%esp
    0x0804918c <+26>:   lea    -0x1e(%ebp),%eax
    0x0804918f <+29>:   push   %eax
    0x08049190 <+30>:   call   0x8049030 <puts@plt>
    0x08049195 <+35>:   add    $0x8,%esp
    0x08049198 <+38>:   nop
    0x08049199 <+39>:   leave  
    0x0804919a <+40>:   ret
```

I would like to create a buffer overflow to `jump` into address `0x080491a1`, the address of `<return_input>`, so that the output will be printed twice.

So finally I do:

```
$ printf "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDD\xa1\x91\x04\x08" | ./c.exe
```

As I understand it, this means:

*10 times 'A', 10 times 'B', 10 times 'C'*

In order to overflow the buffer. Continuing on to *6 times 'D'*, and then to my 4 byte payload. Together it is 40 bytes, 10 bytes more than the size of my buffer.

I expect it to `jump` to that address, because the `ret` instruction in the  stack should be now overwritten with my payload. But instead:

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDD��
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I could not replicate the result that the author gets in the book:

> shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ printf
>   “AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDD\xed\x83\x04\x08” | ./overflow

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDí
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDò
```

Can someone explain how to make the `jump` without the segfault? I have tried go step by step in gdb, but even then I could not see the payload address after `ret`.

At what position must I give the payload in order for it to execute without causing a segfault?

The code was compiled with the following flags:

`cc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -ggdb -m32 -fno-stack-protector -o $@ -no-pie -fno-PIE -z execstack $<`

Comment: When you want to abuse undefined behavior, like buffer overflows, you need to know the exact details of the compiler being used and how it manages the stack.

Comment: Where to find out? I thought I am using the same compiler as in book, ordinary `gcc`, so where  can I find out, how it compile my case?

Comment: Use the force\b\b\b\b\bdebugger, Luke. ;-)

Comment: @Herdsman Every version of GCC is different.

Comment: Dont get it. What does `force\b\b\b\b\bdebuger` mean? @thebusybee

Comment: @Herdsman Can you dump the return_input function as well?

Comment: @Herdsman force\b\b\b\b\bdebugger is supposed to be a joke. \b is a backspace. Like "Use the force, I mean the debugger."

Comment: @user253751 edited, added dumped `return_input`

Comment: You might notice that your `return_input` allows pushes ebp. You have 30 bytes for `ar`, then the old value of ebp, then the return address. How many bytes before the return address is that?

Comment: @user253751 What? pushing of `%ebp` is part of function convention, I am pushing (better said `return_input`) 2 params: the second: `%eax` (which holds the address: ebp-30, buffer), the first is immediate value, which represents the string `" %s"`. So i do not know what do you mean `how many bytes are pushed before ret` 3*4=12 (old ebp, address, and string). So what do you mean?

Comment: @Herdsman What are you trying to overwrite with your buffer overflow?

Comment: I am trying to JUMP to address after exceedig buffer space. That means, that after 36 bytes I write my payload (4 bytes) with address to overwrite the `ret` instruction (so the address will be popped and moved to eip - as does `ret`), and ouput the input 2 times (for the second time when jumped back by my payload). It is nothing so speciall, only educational to see it executes my payload instead of SEGFAULT. That is my purpose

Comment: use GDB.........